# TYPO3 TypoScript mark navigation active

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

How can I mark a navigation active in TypoScript?

Navigation TypoScript looks like this:

```
NAVIMAIN = HMENU
NAVIMAIN.entryLevel = 0
#NAVIMAIN.excludeUidList = 

NAVIMAIN {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="cf">|</ul>

        noBlur = 1
        NO = 1
        NO.ATagTitle.field = title
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>  
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>

        ACT = 1
        ACT.ATagParams = class="act"
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li> |</li>  
    }
}
```

Thanks at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NAVIMAIN = HMENU
NAVIMAIN {
    entryLevel = 0
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="cf">|</ul>

        noBlur = 1
        NO = 1
        NO {
            ATagTitle.field = title
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>  
        }
        ACT < .NO
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes thanks just found it as well ... that works fine for url.de/page

but for rot page it does not work ...

Comment: depending on your page structure (I assume you have root-page and a shortcut 'home' beneath with other siblings) you have problems with the active state of shortcut pages. here you need to modify your TS menu with TS conditions. depending on 'current' page you need to set `.alwaysActivePIDlist`

Comment: No its no shortcut for the home. Home is in root node (globe)